# How do I "remember" a target for multiple commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Let's say I want to target the nearest player to 5, 5, 5 and teleport them to 50, 50, 50:

```
/tp @p[x=5,y=5,z=5] 50 50 50
```

but then I want to `/kill` them (specifically in this order). This would not work:

```
/kill @p[x=5,y=5,z=5]
```

because there may be another player there that is different.
**How do I remember who I selected first to target them in multiple commands?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tagging

Tagging is a way to select specific players that have the tag. They can be added or removed at any time, and multiple players can have them. We do this via

```
/tag @p add MyTag
```

and remove via

```
/tag @p remove MyTag
```

We can select everyone with a tag with the selector `@a[tag=MyTag]`.

## How to Fix This Example

First, instead of teleporting the player let's tag them:

```
/tag @p[x=5,y=5,z=5] add selected
```

We added a tag we call `selected` to them. Now teleport them:

```
/tp @a[tag=selected] 50 50 50
```

Now kill them:

```
/kill @a[tag=selected]
```

Now take the tag away:

```
/tag @a[tag=selected] remove selected
```

Comment: When an entity is killed, it loses all its tags. When a player is killed and respawns, are their tags kept or lost?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 sorry your reply seemed to slip my eye. Tags are kept when a player respawns.